# Read existing SMS using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. Can someone point me to a way to read existing SMSs using Xamarin Forms.
I know we can do it using Android specific libraries (and probably with iOS specific libraries as well). But, I want to use a library that will help me avoid using platform specific library.

Comment: iOS doesn't have any public API to allow you to access SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use platform specific code for this. Remember; all libraries out there actually *are* platform specific code but just offer you an abstraction. This includes Xamarin.Forms itself.

As mentioned by Jason in the comments, you aren't going to be able to do this on iOS altogether, they do not allow to read or sends texts directly. So you should probably rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Jason and Gerald Versluis, I was ignorant of the fact that iOS does not allow apps to read SMS. Thank you for pointing this out to me.